# Get all documents in content belonging to a particular library in SOQL

Tags: soql, content, contentversion

I need to get documents of a particular library using SOQL.

```
SELECT title FROM ContentVersion where Contendocument.Parent.Contentworkspace.name='EMEA Sales'
```

The error i get is INVALID_FIELD: on Contendocument.Parent.Contentworkspace.name

The ERD model for content objects can be viewed here
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_content.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
ID workspaceId = [SELECT Id FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = 'EMEA Sales'][0].Id;
List <ContentVersion> allDocuments = [SELECT Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocument.ParentId = :workspaceId]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Retrieving documents from a library using filter like

`[SELECT Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocument.ParentId = :workspaceId]`

may be incorrect, if document is shared with several libraries, and workspaceId is not equal to the library it was initially uploaded to.

Example: Doc1 was uploaded in Library1, and then shared with Libary2. If you use Libary2.Id as workspaceId in the query above, it will return 0 results, because ContentDocument.ParentId will be equal to Library1.Id.

Document and Library sharing dependencies can be viewed in ContentWorkspaceDoc object. So I would try this query:

```
[SELECT Title 
 FROM ContentVersion 
 WHERE ContentDocumentId in (SELECT ContentDocumentId 
                             FROM ContentWorkspaceDoc 
                             WHERE ContentWorkspaceId = :workspaceId
                              )
]
```

If you need to export all document versions, you can look at [this solution](http://salesforce-practices.blogspot.ru/2014/04/mass-export-of-crm-content-from.html).