# Mass Delete Documents In Content Libary

Tags: content, enterprise, bulk-delete

I've been asked to delete 80 outdated documents from our content libary is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: This thread has the solution for getting all the documents from the content library. How about getting those ids and execute delete dml against them? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15782/get-all-documents-in-content-belonging-to-a-particular-library-in-soql

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to delete the documents in content lib - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Hid3AAC